# Microsoft Edge does not trust self-signed certificate even after import

Tags: iis, ssl-certificate, certificate, microsoft-edge, self-signed

**Windows Server 2022** v.21H2, **IIS** 10, **Microsoft Edge** v. 114

The machine has no access to the Internet.

I open **Windows PowerShell (Admin)** and generate a self-signed certificate:

```
New-SelfSignedCertificate -subject "myserver.mydomain.local" -FriendlyName "The big brown fox" -NotAfter (Get-Date).AddYears(20) -CertStoreLocation "Cert:\LocalMachine\My"
```

A new certificate immediately appears in **IIS**/**myserver**/**Server Certificates**.
I specify it in **IIS**/**myserver**/**Sites**/**Default Web Site**/**Bindings**/**https**/**SSL certificate**.

On the same machine I open **Microsoft Edge** and navigate to https://myserver.mydomain.local. I get a **⚠ Not secure** message in the address bar and **Your connection isn't private** message instead of the actual page. I press **Advanced** and choose **Continue to myserver.mydomain.local (unsafe)**. The warning in the address bar remains. I click on it, then on **⚠ Your connection to this site isn't secure >**, then on . **Certificate Viewer** opens. I export the certificate as *.crt file, double click on it and the Windows default certificate viewer opens. I press **Install Certificate** and install the certificate into **Local Machine** → **Trusted Root Certification Authorities**. I reopen **Edge** and the site. The warning in the address bar remains.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: https://docs.jexusmanager.com/tutorials/ssl-diagnostics.html Run a report and the cause should be clear.

Comment: This link should help you: [https://ali-dev.medium.com/how-to-trust-any-self-signed-ssl-certificate-in-ie11-and-edge-fa7b416cac68](https://ali-dev.medium.com/how-to-trust-any-self-signed-ssl-certificate-in-ie11-and-edge-fa7b416cac68).

Comment: samwu, why do you suggest me to do what I have already done?! Also, this article is 5 years old and the UI elements described there do not exist in Edge anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Solved. The first argument in the certificate generation should be **-DnsName** instead of **-Subject**:

New-SelfSignedCertificate **-DnsName** myserver.mydomain.local -FriendlyName "The big brown fox" -NotAfter (Get-Date).AddYears(20) -CertStoreLocation Cert:\LocalMachine\My